# I receive an Application error while trying to access the app in production

Tags: build, tail

My Heroku App is not working anymore and is giving me back the attached error. Can someone help in troubleshooting? I have read about a plan upgrade needed in some cases, is this error related to upgrade needed?

The app have been working properly and suddenly started giving me back this error. Discovered today.

Comment: What is the issue ? I don't see any trace...

Answer (score 0):

Under the **Overview** tab what do you see next to:

> web npm start

It should say **On**. If not you need to click "Configure Dynos" and turn it on.